# CSS: What are the behavior rules for a "width: auto" container with inline-flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, display

I was trying to create a list / table view with dynamic width using flexbox, and encountered a behavior I couldn't really wrap my head around. The result I'm trying to achieve is a width that fits the content of the list, at its' widest point.

```css
.main {
  width: auto;
  background: rgb(233, 148, 148);
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.label,
.value {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}

.label {
  text-align: end;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.value {
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some Label</div>
      <div class="value">Some value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some label 2</div>
      <div class="value">Other val</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Third label</div>
      <div class="value">
        <div>N/A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What it boils down to, is that the width seems to be determined by the total characters count, and not the widest point, as I would expect. You can edit the HTML and remove the N/A, for example, and the width will decrease.

When I switch to `display: inline-block` with `white-space: nowrap`, the width is as expected, but the "columns" are not aligned.

```css
.main {
  width: auto;
  background: rgb(233, 148, 148);
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.label,
.value {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}

.label {
  text-align: end;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.value {
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some Label</div>
      <div class="value">Some value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some label 2</div>
      <div class="value">Other val</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Third label</div>
      <div class="value">
        <div>N/A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What causes the large width to occur when the display is `inline-flex`? Is there a way to get the behavior I'm trying to achieve? I know it can probably be resolved with `display: grid`, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it can probably be resolved with display: grid, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

It might be difficult if you do not handle the grid-layout fine enough yet, but it looks not that much complicated if you use the grid system ;)

For the width, look at `max-content`.

simple example:

```css
.main {
  width: max-content;
  background: rgb(233, 148, 148);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.label,
.value {
  padding: 4px;
}

.label {
  text-align: end;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.value {
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some Label</div>
      <div class="value">Some value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some label 2</div>
      <div class="value">Other val</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Third label</div>
      <div class="value">
        <div>N/A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In the past ,before `flex` & `grid` , `display` would use the table-layout.

```css
.main {
      display:table;
      background: rgb(233, 148, 148);
    }
  .container {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .label, .value {
    padding: 4px;
    display:table-cell;
  }
  .label {
    text-align: end;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
  }
  .value {
    text-align: start;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some Label</div>
      <div class="value">Some value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Some label 2</div>
      <div class="value">Other val</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Third label</div>
      <div class="value">
        <div>N/A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that grid is probably simpler :) I perhaps should've clarified I mean a "lower level solution" simple, not in terms of styling complexity. I'm also trying to understand the source of the odd width behavior, and if it is possible to implement with flexbox.

Comment: the problem is that you try to have a grid system on a row, but also matching columns :), so grid (or table) would match while flex will do one or the other at a time. @O.Aroesti